# Using 'creates' arg in Ansible shell module

Tags: ansible

When using the "creates" argument in the shell module, can this be a path to a directory? Or does it have to be a file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why don't you just try that yourself? The short answer is: Yes it can be anything that is then visible in the file system

```
---
- name: Test create arg of shell
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: Set up working area
      shell: mktemp -d
      register: workdir
    - name: Working Area
      debug:
        msg: "{{ workdir }}"

    - name: Create a file
      shell: touch {{ workdir.stdout }}/test-file
      args:
        creates: "{{ workdir.stdout }}/test-file"
    - name: "Test if it get's created again"
      shell: touch {{ workdir.stdout }}/test-file
      args:
        creates: "{{ workdir.stdout }}/test-file"

    - name: Create a directory
      shell: mkdir {{ workdir.stdout }}/test-directory
      args:
        creates: "{{ workdir.stdout }}/test-directory"
    - name: "Test if it get's created again"
      shell: mkdir {{ workdir.stdout }}/test-directory
      args:
        creates: "{{ workdir.stdout }}/test-directory"
    - name: Cleanup
      shell: "rm -rf {{ workdir.stdout }}"

# vim: set ts=2 sts=2 fenc=utf-8 list:
```